# Windows Server 2008 R2 Accessing NFS share without AD or NIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, nfs

I'm trying to mount an NFS share on our NetApp SAN on Windows 2008 R2 & services for NFS.  Using XP I have no problem mounting this share without a username/NIS/pswd file etc, but the new functionality in 2008 seems to insist on either using AD or an NIS server (to "streamline" Services for NFS MS removed user account mapping) [see Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753302(WS.10).aspx).

1. When I go to map the share using "map network drive" no combination of "root", no username, no password, my username works.
2. Using the command line `mount -o anon \\172... :n` or `mount -o -u:root \\172... :n` either gives me a network error 53 or 67 error

Is it possible with 2008 to mount an NFS share without AD or NIS?  If so what am I doing wrong?

(Security is taken care off by IP address permissions and VLANs)